# How to create symbol text strings for plots in R

Tags: r, text, plot, expression, symbols

I have a plot and would like to add some regression statistics (e.g. F, R2, p) in the plot area. I am familiar with `text()`, but have been unable to find a comprehensive source of information with examples on how to build text strings with mathematical symbols, sub-and superscripts, etc. Any sources with detailed examples greatly appreciated.

For example, I have a simple linear regression that I would like to extract the stats from and add them to my plot. For example

```
reg1 <- lm(WW1 ~ PC1, data = WW_Data)
```

I would like to have something like `F1,69 = 14.38, p = < 0.001, R2adj = 0.16` where "1,69" and "adj" is subscript, and "p" is in *italics*.

**EDIT**:

Thanks to `@Backlin` for a great answer to my question. I have expanded on it a bit so that if you get a highly significant p-value the code substitutes "< 0.001" and rounded all the statistics to 2 decimal places, except the p-value which I have rounded to 3.

```
WW_Data <- data.frame(WW1=rnorm(10), PC1=1:10)
reg1 <- lm(WW1~PC1, WW_Data)
sreg1 <- summary(reg1)
plot(0, 0)
text(0, .2, eval(substitute(
    expression(list(F[list(fn,fd)]==fv,italic(p)==pv,R[adj]^2==R2adj)),
        list(fv = round(sreg1$fstatistic[1],2), fn = sreg1$fstatistic[2],
             fd = sreg1$fstatistic[3], pv = ifelse(sreg1$coefficients["PC1",4] < 0.001, "< 0.001",round(sreg1$coefficients["PC1",4],3)),
             R2adj = round(sreg1$adj.r.squared,2)))))
```

Comment: Thank you. `?plotmath` is a good source for individual symbols and things like super and subscripts, but it does little to help me build a longer expression as I described above. For example, how to get `F1,69`with "1,69" as subscript. I can easily get the "1", but I cannot figure out how to get the ",69" in subscript. Any other pages you can recommend with more comprehensive examples, including how to get symbols like "commas"?

Comment: See also `?expression` and the examples in `?text`. I won't post an answer since I don't really have the expertise in this. Somebody else will, no doubt.

Comment: I really loving the in's and out's of R, but I find it SUPER challenging to have to spend hours just to learn how to add a single line of text to a plot. I have no problem adding a "1" subscript after "F" in my example, but the ",69" is not obvious in any of the examples described in `text`, `expression`, or `plotmath`.

Comment: Som det ser ut nu, så lär p-värden < .001 ge texten `p =< 0.001`. Om du vill bli av med `=` kan du istället skriva `italic(p)pv` eller `italic(pv)~pv`. `~` fungerar som en avdelare mellan två komponenter som man kan sätta in om expression inte kan skilja dem åt, t.ex. om man vill ha två grekiska tecken på rad: `alpha~beta`. Tog en bra stund innan jag hittade den, men den är rysligt användbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have struggled a lot with it myself too, but it is actually all in `?plotmath`. Your expression would be the following,

```
# Fixed expression
text(x, y, expression(list(F[list(1,69)]==14.38,italic(p)<0.001,R[adj]^2==0.16)))

# Using the values of your lm
sreg1 <- summary(reg1)
text(x, y, eval(substitute(
    expression(list(F[list(fn,fd)]==fv,italic(p)==pv,R[adj]^2==R2adj)),
        list(fv = sreg1$fstatistic[1], fn = sreg1$fstatistic[2],
             fd = sreg1$fstatistic[3], pv = sreg1$coefficients["PC1",4],
             R2adj = sreg1$adj.r.squared))))
```

Here's a dummy example of what it looks like.

```
WW_Data <- data.frame(WW1=rnorm(10), PC1=1:10)
reg1 <- lm(WW1~PC1, WW_Data)
sreg1 <- summary(reg1)
plot(0, 0)
text(0, .2, eval(...)) # The expression above
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes the examples are a bit abstract, because you must paste them into `R` to learn from them.

Comment: I did not realize you could send the results of `summary` to an object and then extract the results. This is very useful!

Comment: Yeah, I agree, and sometimes you don't get it right because you overlooked some minute detail. That's when SO comes in handy.