# How to place multiple lines of text on plot, including superscript, in R

Tags: r, text, plot

On this sample plot

```
plot(1:10)
```

I would like to place three separate lines in the bottom right area:

```
slope=xx
P=yy
R^2=zz
```

With a superscript ‘2’ in R^2. I’ve tried a few things using text and bquote, but I can’t get it all to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878974/how-to-create-symbol-text-strings-for-plots-in-r ; you might be able to add newline characters `\\n` in the strings to get the bits on separate lines

Comment: `plotrix::corner.label()` might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use text():

```
plot(1:10)
text(8,2,"slope=xx")
text(8,1.5,"P=yy")
text(8,1,expression(R^2== zz)) # you can use expression() for superscripts
```